# Notify showing nothing on vuex subscribe

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework

I'm trying to show a notification when I try to create a user in my pwa. to do that I'm subscribing the mutation that set the notification and then calling the notify but nothing is showed and no errors on console.

That's what I'm trying to do:

```js
export default {
  ...,
  mounted: function() {
    var self = this
    this.$store.subscribe(function(mutation, state) {
      if (mutation === 'usuario/setError') {
        self.$q.notify({
          message: state.usuario.error.mensagem,
          timeout: 3000,
          type: state.usuario.error.sucesso ? 'positive' : 'negative',
          position: 'top'
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I tried import Notify from qusar and call Notify.create but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, instead use subscribe I could use watch from vue and watch the changes on a computed. This way:

```js
export default {
 ...,
 computed: {
    error: function() {
      return this.$store.state.usuario.error
    }
  },
  watch: {
    error: function(newError, oldError) {
      console.log(newError)
      this.$q.notify({
        message: newError.mensagem,
        timeout: 3000,
        type: newError.sucesso ? 'positive' : 'negative',
        position: 'top'
      })
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `if (mutation.type === 'usuario/setError')`, if that doesn't work console log mutation to see what the type is and use that.